# Constrained mixed integer optimization: genetic algorithm used with SimEvents. How can I set a simulation output as a constraint?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, simulink

I'm using the **genetic algorithm** from the MATLAB Global Optimization Toolbox with **SimEvents**, in order to implement a **mixed integer optimization** making use of simulation outputs to evaluate the fitness function. My model is pretty similar to the one described in this video from MathWorks website:

http://www.mathworks.it/videos/optimizing-manufacturing-production-processes-68961.html

Reading the documentation, I found that *ga* can solve constrained problems only if such constraints are linear inequalities. The constraints are supposed to be written as functions of the problem's variables, that in this case are the number of resources used during the simulation.

I would like, instead, **to set a constraint that takes into account another simulation output** (e.g. the drain utilization), i.e. minimize

```
objfun = backlog*10000 + cost
```

where *backlog* is a simulation output (obtained using simOut.get), considering the following constraint:

```
drain_utilization > 0.7
```

where *drain*_ *utilization* is another simulation output (again, obtained using simOut.get).

Is it possible or this feature is not supported by the Global Optimization Toolbox? 
Thank you in advance and forgive me for any improper term, but I'm new to the Global Optimization Toolbox.

Comment: You can always modify the cost/fitness function so that if the constraint is violated then the cost is "large" in comparison to if it is not violated.

Comment: It is a nice "trick" to easily tackle to problem. But the point is that if you do not know exactly how to "value" the constraint in terms of cost, you will probably not find the optimal solution (i.e. you know that `backlog*10000` allows to consider how backlogs affect the final cost, but you miss the corresponding multiplicative term for drain_utilization. Anyway, thank you very much for your advice! @PhilGoddard